# Value of member variable disappears in CodeIgniter/PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a situation of loosing value stored in `$member` variable.

```
class User extends CI_Controller {
    protected $message;

    function list()
    {
        $data['message'] = $this->message; // it's empty
        $this->load->view('view', $data);
    }

    function delete($id)
    {
        $this->user_model->delete($id);
        $this->message = "Success";

        redirect('user/list');
    }

}
```

The reason of using a redirect is to get a clean URL. I get empty value for `$this->message` in `list()` after getting redirected.

I even tried making it **static**, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using flash messages:

```
function delete($id)
{
    $this->user_model->delete($id);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Success');

    redirect('user/list');
}
```

For this you are likely to need to load session library in constructor of you controller:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

In your view use this:

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message');?>
```

You can preserve data in flash messages for several requests like this:

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('message');
```

Have a look at [this link](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata)